# GTA5 dataset. After generating tfrecod file, it is about 50G. It seems that it can NOT finish one epoch during reading data

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

The GTA5 contains 24966 images. After I transform them into one tfrecord file, it is about 50G.

And when I read this large file, it seems that it could NOT finish one epoch. I mean that **it did output part of data**. But during the reading, it will raise the following error. 
It reads some data out at the beginning. But at the middle stage, like after 948 steps, it will raise errors. I suspect if it is because that my tfrecord file is too large?

Could someone give me some advices?
Thank you in advance.

```
Step 946
(8, 512, 1024, 3) (8, 512, 1024, 1)
Step 947
(8, 512, 1024, 3) (8, 512, 1024, 1)
Step 948
(8, 512, 1024, 3) (8, 512, 1024, 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1323, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1302, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: RandomShuffleQueue '_1_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 8, current size 3)
     [[Node: shuffle_batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_UINT8], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, shuffle_batch/n)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PycharmProjects/adversarial_gradient/datasets/GTA5/convert_gta5.py", line 187, in <module>
    l = sess.run(label_batch)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 889, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1120, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1317, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1336, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: RandomShuffleQueue '_1_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 8, current size 3)
     [[Node: shuffle_batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_UINT8], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, shuffle_batch/n)]]

Caused by op 'shuffle_batch', defined at:
  File "D:/PycharmProjects/adversarial_gradient/datasets/GTA5/convert_gta5.py", line 163, in <module>
    img_batch, label_batch = inputs(params, shuffle=True)
  File "D:/PycharmProjects/adversarial_gradient/datasets/GTA5/convert_gta5.py", line 148, in inputs
    return generate_batch([img, label], params, shuffle, num_examples)
  File "D:/PycharmProjects/adversarial_gradient/datasets/GTA5/convert_gta5.py", line 121, in generate_batch
    min_after_dequeue=min_queue_examples)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\input.py", line 1225, in shuffle_batch
    name=name)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\input.py", line 796, in _shuffle_batch
    dequeued = queue.dequeue_many(batch_size, name=name)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\data_flow_ops.py", line 464, in dequeue_many
    self._queue_ref, n=n, component_types=self._dtypes, name=name)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 2417, in _queue_dequeue_many_v2
    component_types=component_types, timeout_ms=timeout_ms, name=name)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2956, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1470, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
```

Comment: i would suggest to make multiple files and read them by batches